# List comprehension with counter in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to add loop counter to the comprehension?

For example, the comprehension without counter:

```
for c <- ["a", "b"], do: c            # => ["a", "b"]
```

How can I add counter to it? Something like this:

```
for c <- ["a", "b"], do: {counter, c} # => [{0, "a"}, {1, "b"}]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use [`Enum.with_index`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2):

```
iex(1)> for {value, index} <- Enum.with_index(["a", "b"]), do: {value, index}
[{"a", 0}, {"b", 1}]
```